# How to set wallpaper in Nautilus Desktop

Tags: raspbian, pixel, desktop

I have installed Nautilus and set as the default file manager. I have also setup Nautilus to manage the desktop. However, my desktop now looks like this:

[image: Black Desktop with Icons]

How do I change to wallpaper.

The Appearance Settings don't work. I think that that change the settings for PcManFM, not Nautilus.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the desktop?

Comment: I get a context menu with the following items:

`New Folder`, `New Document`, `Open Terminal`, `Paste`, `Organise Desktop by Name` and `Keep Aligned`