# How to get Nautilus as a desktop

Tags: lxsession, pi-a+, lxpanel

Installing Nautilus is easy. But I can't manage to get Nautilus as a desktop. I have found forums around my topic but to no avail:

- [Nautilus as desktop manager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=185071)
- [How to set wallpaper in Nautilus Desktop](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68612/how-to-set-wallpaper-in-nautilus-desktop)

How do I get it done to get Nautilus as desktop?

Comment: As your question is the only relevant one that showed up in my search, I would have to guess that you're somewhat of a pioneer wrt Nautilus & RPi. You might pore over [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151847/how-to-change-the-window-manager-on-a-raspberry-pi) for clues.

Comment: It's a bit old but this may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/155897/how-to-make-nautilus-the-default-file-manager-in-lxde. Ignore the title - read the text :-)